# Don't require a password when waking

Tags: macos, password

Is there a way to *not* require a password when I wake my MBA (open the lid)? I'm aware of the security implications. I'm running Lion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System Preferences > Security & Privacy

Uncheck the box "Require Password Immediately"

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Boy is my face red -- I knew I was supposed to look for Security but for the life of me I couldn't find it under Sys Prefs.